# How to get Chrome to throw exception when changing url if it fails

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, exception

I have a reference to a new window opened with js

```
var theNewTab="";
theNewTab = window.open(theURL, 'winRef');
```

then I change the url in the as the user clicks on another link in the parent window using

```
theNewTab.location.href = targetLink;
theNewTab.focus();
```

The problem i'm having with chrome that id doesn't throw exception if the the window doesn't exist anymore "closed" unlink FF & IE which im using to open the window again.

```
try {
   theNewTab.location.href = targetLink;
   theNewTab.focus();
}catch(err) {
   theNewTab = window.open(theURL, 'winRef');
   theNewTab.focus();
}
```

PS: I tried to use "window.open" every time but if the window already open, id does not reload the page or it does but it doesn't re-execute the script I have in document ready I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you need.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  var theNewTab = null;

  function openNewTab(theURL) {
    if (theNewTab == null || theNewTab.closed == true) {
      theNewTab = window.open(theURL);
    } else {
      theNewTab.location.href = theURL;
    }
    theNewTab.focus();
  };

  // use the function when you need it
  $('a').click(function() {
    openNewTab($(this).attr('href'));
  });
</script>
```

Is this example helpful for you?

Comment: Okay I dont know why you code works! lol maybe because its inside a function! but thanks heaps :)